# Vertical divider CSS

Tags: html, css

I am creating a vertical divider, that works fine. But the CSS is cumbersome.

The CSS is:

```
.headerDivider1 {
border-left:1px solid #38546d;height:80px;position:absolute;right:250px;top:10px;
}

.headerDivider2 {
border-left:1px solid #16222c;height:80px;position:absolute;right:249px;top:10px;
}
```

The HTML is:

```
<div class="headerDivider1"></div><div class="headerDivider2"></div>
```

The result is:

[image]

How could I tidy the HTML and CSS up?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
.headerDivider {
     border-left:1px solid #38546d; 
     border-right:1px solid #16222c; 
     height:80px;
     position:absolute;
     right:249px;
     top:10px; 
}

<div class="headerDivider"></div>
```

Comment: It's the height!

Answer (score 5):

```
<div class="headerdivider"></div>
```

and

```
.headerdivider {
    border-left: 1px solid #38546d;
    background: #16222c;
    width: 1px;
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 250px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for vertical divider only

```
.divider {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using the `after` property for vertical divider using CSS because it's neither content nor a border.

```
.block {
  position: relative; /* ADDED */
}

.block:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  right: -10px; 
  height: 80%; 
}

.block:last-child:after {
  display: none; /* Hide the divider for the last block */
}
```