# How to create a vertical divider in css?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a react component and want to create a vertical divider(1cm high) between a text and an image:

```
<div class="container">
  <span>goodmorning hello user!</span>
  <span class="divider" /> <img src="./bell.png" />
</div>
```

This is the css I am using:

```
.container {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

.divider {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 10%;
  bottom: 40%;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

How can I get the vertical line between the excl. mark and image?
[codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/l7yw0mo85q)

Comment: the html isn't valid, there is no self closing span... you should use `<span></span>`. Btw you can simply add border to the text

Comment: Try this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675371/vertical-divider-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `position: absolute` from the css and add some other styles for the exact size you want. Here is a simple example I made based on your code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/kj1monoxo

Comment: I want the divider to be 1cm-2cm height, How can I do this?

Comment: You can actually use `height: 1cm;` if you want to

Answer (score 1):

instead of border to an empty span element why won't you try width:

```
.divider {
  position: relative;
  min-width:2px;
  max-width:2px;
  background-color:#000;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 0.25%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using Tailwind CSS**

Too Easy!

```
<div className="w-6 border-r-2 border-black mr-2">&nbsp;</div>
```

**Alternatively, you can add CSS**

```
.divider{
width: 1.5rem;
border-right: 2px;
border-color: black;
margin: 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parent container needs to have `display: flex` and remove the absolute positioning.

[CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wwqn3zmrz8)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.divider {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>goodmorning hello user!</span>
  <span class="divider"> </span>
  <img src="https://uploads.codesandbox.io/uploads/user/1755a454-9fe4-4200-8cf7-f76e5c1cbdec/hE5V-bell.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using divs which are by default block elements, then use `display: flex` on the container:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.divider {
  width: 1px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 1cm;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>goodmorning hello user!</span>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/golden-bell_1262-6415.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg&ve=1" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
               .vl {
     border-left: 6px solid green;
        height: 500px;
      }
          </style>
           </head>
        <body>

          <h2>Vertical Line</h2>

            <div class="vl"></div>
```